# In Bayesian modeling, are there any approaches to score the confidence of the predicted distribution, instead of just the point estimate?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, scoring-rules

In a situation where one is predicting a distribution, rather than just a point estimate, what are some approaches to check the goodness of fit on observed data? The goal here would be to get a metric that encapsulates the confidence of a given prediction (wider distributions would have a "worse" metric). Are posterior predictive checks used for this? Are there any other methods?

Comment: Validation set marginal log likelihood. This is the basis of Bayesian methods. I'd recommend Murphy's "probabilistic machine learning" book for basics on these sorts of things (e.g. GP chapter).

Comment: @Oxonon would marginal log-likelihood work for non-binary outcomes? Say I want to predict an outcome that follows the beta distribution [0,1] (I'd like to compare my predicted .50 to the validation set .80 and also capture the confidence in my prediction in the evaluation metric).

Comment: Yes, it'd work for any distribution. Intuitively it is just a measure of how likely the test point is on average with respect to your model. If you are confidently wrong, your test point will be very unlikely, and the marginal likelihood very low, and vice versa if you are confidently right. If you are right/wrong but fairly uncertain, it'll be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Oh i see, is this basically just the log pmf for a discrete dist? For instance, if your prior (predicted distribution) follows a beta distribution, but your likelihood is binomial then your posterior predictive is beta-binomial - you'd take the logpmf of the observed # of successes under that bb distribution? I think we are both talking about this? https://vasishth.github.io/bayescogsci/book/expected-log-predictive-density-of-a-model.html

Comment: That sounds about right. I had a quick skim of that book --- pretty sure the chapter after what you linked is equivalent: evaluating this quantity on a validation set. Gelman is someone I'd trust on this topic and one of the citations in that book is a paper of his the title of which sounds like exactly what you're after --- I'd suggest reading that to see if he has any more insight.